# How does "would" work in this sentence?

Tags: usage, modal-verbs

Why is "would" used in this sentence?

Question A: I've tied the knot for 42 years. It's incredible. The time pass so quickly. Is this sentence right?

Answer B: The expression "tie the knot" means to get married - the ceremony itself, so in your sentence it **would be** "I/we tied the knot 42 years ago".

Comment: Would is subjunctive of `will`, i.e. it refers to your wishes/desires, conditional on something. Here it means you would say "we tied the knot 42 years ago", if you wish to write correctly.  It is a polite way of giving advice.

Comment: Thanks. If I replace "would" with "is", is it right? It is "we tied the knot 42 years ago.

Comment: Maybe if you were a minister who has been performing marriage ceremonies for the last 42 years you might say, “I’ve tied the knot for 42 years.” or maybe “I’ve been tying the knot for 42 years.”

Comment: What @Jim said. In practice, it's not worth thinking up contrived contexts to justify using a Present Perfect verb form in Question A above. Just note that it's an ***error*** - the intended sense ***should*** be expressed using *I tied the knot **42 years ago*** or similar. Note that in my comment and your "Answer B", ***should*** can be replaced by ***could*** or ***must*** - or by plain **IS**, if you don't want to bother with pointless "indirection, deference, hesitancy,...".

Comment: Sorry, I'm asking about the difference between "it would be..." and "it is..." in the above sentence. Could you explain?